Prediction intervals of functions of inputs
I have a linear regression model I have estimated which is of the form Y = a + b*X + e.
I know how to construct the prediction interval for the outcomes of Y given some value X (say X1), but I was wondering if there was any formula/methodology I could use for estimating prediction intervals for different functions of variables?
Not sure how to formulate this mathematically, but for example if:
House Price = a + b * Number of Bedrooms + e
I would like to be able to estimate the prediction interval of the difference between prices of 2 and 3 bedroom houses.
My initial thought here would be to just put 3-2 into Number of Bedrooms here but I suspect there is an interraction effect / compounding of the standard error due to two different estimates being inputted.
I suppose if you just treat it as Y1 ~ Normal(mu1, sd1) and Y2 ~ Normal(mu2, sd2) where mu and sd are determined by the regression estimates then you could just estimate the distribution of Y1 - Y2 for example (assuming there's no correlation)? I would guess that this is correct but I haven't been able to find anything that confirms/denies this.
Either this or create a new linear model where the X and Y values are each defined as the differences, and find the prediction interval using that?

your idea of having Y1 and Y2 come from two different normal distributions is a good start. But it's missing the fact that these estimates are correlated (since they depend on the same estimates of the regression coefficients). How comfortable are you with matrix arithmetic?
